# Is TypeScript not aware of type checking inside other functions?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using typescript in React and I'm facing the following problem.

Here is a function that checks that arr is an Array and is not empty.

```
export const isNotEmptyArr = (arr?: unknown[]) => {
  return Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length > 0  // If true, arr is not undefined.
}
```

I think that if isNotEmptyArr(data) is true for data that may be undefined, then data is guaranteed to be not undefined.

```
  const { data } = useSWR(  // data is possibly undefined
    ...
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isNotEmptyArr(data)) {
      setName(data[0].name)  // error occured - TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
    }
  }, [data])
```

But, typescript generates an error as shown above, saying that data may be undefined. Why is that so? Is there a beautiful way to solve this problem?

For now, I am solving this problem using optional chaining (like this: `data?.[0].name ?? ''`), but I hope there is a better way.

typescript version: 4.5.4

Comment: No, a typechecker does generally not look inside a function to see what it does when validating a call expression. It only looks at the (possibly inferred) type of the function. Compare the type of `Array.isArray` with the type of `isNotEmptyArray` and notice the difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not by default. You can define a function as a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), and then it will use that type information.

```
function isNotEmptyArr (arr?: unknown[]): arr is unknown[] {
  return Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length > 0  // If true, arr is not undefined.
}
```

Comment: thank you!  I think my code will be cleaner thanks to you.